# Excel crash (closes all workbooks and restarts)

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I have multiple workbooks open, some of which refer to others.

Typically every few days Excel will suddenly just close and restart and try to "recover" the closed workbooks.  Two problems - it often happens in the middle of some VBA code that is updating files.  That is, it is in the middle of a "transaction" so even after restoring files it is necessary to manually determine where it is in the update process and manually step through to avoid redoing the functions part done at the point of the "crash".  Secondly, Excell assigns new names (versions) but of course these are not the names the VBA code is looking for, so all needs to be cleaned up manually.  It would be great if it stopped crashing.
Problem has been there for years but only seemed to start when I switched to a Dell G7 Laptop.  This is a unit designed for gaming.  I have absolutely no interest in gaming but it was the only laptop I could find with a 17 inch screen.  My suspicion, based on nothing but prejudice, is that something with the multiple processors is triggering an event that causes Excel to restart :-).  Running Windows 11 and the Excel in Microsoft 365.

Increased the error trapping in VBA but it does not seem to be trappable incident that is triggering failure.

Comment: Hard to diagnose this. First thing I would try is to repair Office (via Settings / Control Panel). If still happens, try disabling your anti-virus while the code is running (always remember to switch it back on after; and you might want to disconnect from the net while doing so) as AV can force-close Office apps running VBA in some circumstances. When your code is 'updating files', are these Excel workbooks or other types of files? Is 'pure VBA' being used or some other eg FSO, Shell.Application, WScript.Shell? If your code is not too long then please post it (as text).